# ToggleButtonGroup Material Ui - How to arrange 2 by 2 2 rows 2 columns

Tags: reactjs, button, material-ui, alignment, togglebutton

If I use grid within toggle buttons then OnChange event doesn't work

With using Grid or Stack event works fine

How I can arrange 2 by 2 buttons

I can't see any example on this on material ui website

Can anyone please help

```
    const [testTime, setTestTime] = useState<string | null>('1');

    const handleTestTime = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>, newTime: string | null) => {
      console.log(newTime);
      setTestTime(newTime);    
    };

     <Box>
      <Typography variant="body2">
        Toggle Button
      </Typography>
      <ToggleButtonGroup 
        value={testTime}
        exclusive 
        onChange={handleTestTime}>
        <Grid container spacing={1}>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            <ToggleButton value="earlymorning">
              <Stack direction={{ xs: 'column' }}>
                <Typography variant="body2">Early Morning</Typography>
              </Stack>
            </ToggleButton>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            <ToggleButton value="morning">
              <Stack direction={{ xs: 'column' }}>
                <Typography variant="body2">Morning</Typography>
              </Stack>
            </ToggleButton>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            <ToggleButton value="afternoon">
              <Stack direction={{ xs: 'column' }}>
                <Typography variant="body2">Afternoon</Typography>
              </Stack>
            </ToggleButton>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            <ToggleButton value="evening">
              <Stack direction={{ xs: 'column' }}>
                <Typography variant="body2">Evening</Typography>
              </Stack>
            </ToggleButton>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </ToggleButtonGroup>
    </Box>
```

Answer (score 3):

The toggle buttons aren't designed to wrap. You can however make them wrap with:

```
<ToggleButtonGroup
sx={{ flexWrap: "wrap"}}
...>
```

Here is an example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-https-366fsv?file=/demo.tsx:775-798

However, you'll see the spacing is a bit off, and so is the border on the item where the column breaks. I'd love it if someone had a clever way to make this look good too-

Answer (score 0):

You could split the toggle buttons in 2 separate `ToggleButtonGroup`s, that share the same state (that is if you want the selection to be exclusive).

With a bit of css, they will look as one toggle button group.

```
<Stack>
  <ToggleButtonGroup
    orientation="horizontal"
    value={view}
    exclusive
    onChange={handleChange}
  >
    <ToggleButton
      value="list"
      aria-label="list"
      sx={{ borderBottomLeftRadius: 0 }}
    >
      <ViewListIcon />
    </ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton value="module" aria-label="module">
      <ViewModuleIcon />
    </ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton
      value="quilt"
      aria-label="quilt"
      sx={{ borderBottomRightRadius: 0 }}
    >
      <ViewQuiltIcon />
    </ToggleButton>
  </ToggleButtonGroup>
  <ToggleButtonGroup
    orientation="horizontal"
    value={view}
    exclusive
    onChange={handleChange}
  >
    <ToggleButton
      value="list1"
      aria-label="list"
      sx={{ borderTopLeftRadius: 0 }}
    >
      <ViewListIcon />
    </ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton value="module1" aria-label="module">
      <ViewModuleIcon />
    </ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton
      value="quilt1"
      aria-label="quilt"
      sx={{ borderTopRightRadius: 0 }}
    >
      <ViewQuiltIcon />
    </ToggleButton>
  </ToggleButtonGroup>
</Stack>
```

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1IUR.png)

If you want to remove the double border in the middle, you could do so by determining the position of the selected toggle and adjust the border width accordingly:

- If no selection or selection is in the first row: set `sx={{ "& *": { borderTopWidth: 0 } }}` on the second `ToggleButtonGroup`
- If selection is in the second row: set `sx={{ "& *": { borderBottomWidth: 0 } }}` on the first `ToggleButtonGroup`

This is to correctly render the middle border of the selected toggle.